# How to know list of all the files changed in a git workspace

Tags: git, gerrit

Following is my `git` workflow which I plan to automate

1. Clone to an external project
2. Cherry-pick a list of gerrits, once cherypicked these automatically get commited if cherrypick is successful
3. Now for the list of files changed in step2, I need to open them and run a script to modify the contents of each file

I need ideas on how to know the list of files changed and how to open them, please provide your inputs.

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a step 1a of creating a branch - `git branch temp`.

For step 3, to get this list of modified files, run `git diff --name-only temp` to see the file names of everything that has changed since you created temp.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie to the gerrit system , but i think -- git diff -- also do the same thing.
Moreover it also tell the differences in the content of both the files.

Unfortunately no eclipse plugin is available for gerrit till now.

-- git status
You run git status to see if anything has been modified and/or staged since your last commit so you can decide if you want to commit a new snapshot and what will be recorded in it.

This will show all modified files.

Reference http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/Tutorial